# How to get from Caracas to Mount Roraima?

Tags: mountains, mountain-climbing, venezuela

[Mount Roraima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Roraima) is said to be the mountain that one in the Pixar movie "Up" is based on.

Pixar image:

[image]

Photo:

[image]

If I'm in Caracas, what's the simplest land-based way to reach Mount Roraima, and is it climbable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The town you want to get to near the mountain is called [Santa Elena de Uairén](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Elena_de_Uair%C3%A9n).

From Caracas there are direct buses (22 hours) or buses via Ciudad Bolivar (8h + 12h) or Puerto Ordaz (12h + 9h). Bus companies you can try are: [Expresos Los Llanos](http://expresoslosllanos.com), Expressos Caribe, Expressos San Cristobel and Expressos Occidante.

In Santa Elena you can get on a tour, a company with a good description of their tours online is [Kamadac](http://www.abenteuer-venezuela.de/eng/home%20eng.htm).

You can also continue by yourself, the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Roraima) about Mount Roraima has a section 'Ascensions' which describes your options to get to the top.